# .NET resource file only successfully reference when in same folder as MVC views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

I have an MVC3 web application, and I am using .resx resource files for all my views contents. I was keeping the resx files in the same location as the views that were using them, however, if I move the resource files to another folder **in the same project**, I get this error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "Application.Web.Views.Login.LoginStrings.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "Application.Web" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

The custom tool property of the resource is set to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and the build action is set to `Embedded Resource`, so I'm not sure what it could be. This is the first time I have worked with resx files so any help would be appreciated.

This is an example of how I am using the resource class:

```
<ul class="itemised-list">
        <li class="italic">
            @LoginStrings.Info_Login
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>@SharedStrings.Account_Username</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username)
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>@SharedStrings.Account_Password</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="@LoginStrings.Btn_Login" class="button" />
        </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, pretty standard, and this has been working all along. Then I move the resx file to a different location in the project and *bam* runtime error :(

Answer (score 0):

A code sample would help a lot to understand what you are trying to achieve.

One approach would be to use the resources strongly typed. In that case you would have to change the the access modifier of your resource file to internal (in toolbar when you open the .resx file in VS)?

[image]

If you set it to internal (public if it is in a different assembly), the code file for the .resx file will be generated and you should be able to access the resources strongly typed.

This way you could access resources the following way:

```
ResourceFile.ResourceItem
```

Comment: the access modifier is set to public for my default resource file, and no code generated for any regional resource files, so it can't be that, thx anyway tho

Comment: As I mentioned above, a code sample would help to understand why you are running into these issues. How do you access the resources currently?

Comment: There isn't really any code I can show, I simply do the same as you have show above, in the view I just reference the resource class, the problem is that it works fine when the resource file is in the Views folder, but if I move them anywhere else it fails with the above message. strange really, it must be something to do with the copying of the resource file or something